# itext 7 signing problem pkcs1 to pkcs7 adobe reader shows document alterd error

Tags: c#, itext

I need to get a pkcs1 singature from a third party and create a pkcs7 singature in a class derived from IExternalSignatureContainer in itext 7
my problem is that the singature in adobe reader has an error: "document has been alterd or currupted sinse signed".

my code:

```
  public byte[] Sign(Stream data)
        {
            String hashAlgorithm = DigestAlgorithms.SHA256;
            byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(data, DigestAlgorithms.GetMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm));
            data.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            string hashStr = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);

            SaveMetaData(hashStr);
            //sækja undirritunina frá auðkenni
            // this class singns the hash using a third party singature service where the customer confirms the singature using his mobile phone
            // the singature lacs a tsa but is confirmd correnct

            AudkenniSignature audkenniSign = new AudkenniSignature(this.Propperties, this.KtOrPhone, ConfirmString, usePKCS7);
            string authId = audkenniSign.InitSign(hashStr);
            audkenniSign.GetSignatureResult(authId);
            //vinna úr gögnunum
            var user = audkenniSign.UserInfo;
            SignerFullName = user.name;
            SignerIdentifier = user.nationalRegisterId;
            Dal.oResult.addWarning("Undirritari nafn", SignerFullName);
            Dal.oResult.addWarning("Undirritari kennitala", SignerIdentifier);
            Propperties.SignerIDNumber = SignerIdentifier;
            Propperties.SignerName = SignerFullName;
            // if this paramerter si returnd here the ti singature is corrrect but has no tsa, we requer tsa, that is added below.
            Signature = System.Convert.FromBase64String(audkenniSign.Signature);

            byte[] certBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(audkenniSign.SigningCert);
            X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certBytes);

            X509Chain certificateChain = new X509Chain();
            certificateChain.ChainPolicy = new X509ChainPolicy
            {
                RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Offline, // or X509RevocationMode.Offline if you have an OCSP responder
                RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain,
            };
            bool chainBuilt = certificateChain.Build(certificate);
            UsedCerts = new X509Certificate2Collection(certificateChain.ChainElements.Cast<X509ChainElement>().Select(e => e.Certificate).ToArray());

            SigningCertSubject = certificate.Subject;
            SignerCertExpier = certificate.NotAfter.ToShortDateString();
            try
            {
                string[] arr = SigningCertSubject.Split(',');
                string name = arr.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Trim().StartsWith("CN"));
                string serial = arr.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Trim().StartsWith("SERIALNUMBER"));
                name = name.Contains('=') ? name.Split('=')[1] : name;
                serial = serial.Contains('=') ? serial.Split('=')[1] : serial;
                Dal.oResult.addWarning("Nafn ur subject", name);
                Dal.oResult.addWarning("Kennitala ur subjet", serial);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException e)
            {
                throw new Exception("Undirritunin er ólögleg", e);
            }

            // Create an RSACryptoServiceProvider
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)UsedCerts[0].PublicKey.Key;
            RSAParameters rsaParams = UsedCerts[0].GetRSAPublicKey().ExportParameters(false);
            rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParams);

            if (!rsa.VerifyData(ReadStreamToByteArray(data), Signature, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1))
            {
                throw new Exception("Undirritunin er ólögleg, VerifyData");
            }

            if (!rsa.VerifyHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"), Signature))
            {
                throw new Exception("Undirritunin er ólögleg, VerifyHash");
            }

            //búa til keðju úr undirritunarskilvikjunum
            X509CertificateParser parser = new X509CertificateParser();
            Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] chain = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[UsedCerts.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < UsedCerts.Count; i++)
            {
                chain[i] = parser.ReadCertificate(UsedCerts[i].GetRawCertData());
            }
            ITSAClient tsaClient = new TSAClientBouncyCastle(Propperties.TimeServicePropperties.TimeServerURL);

            OcspClientBouncyCastle ocspClient = new OcspClientBouncyCastle(null);
            Collection<byte[]> ocsp = new Collection<byte[]>();
            for (var i = 0; i < chain.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                byte[] encoded = ocspClient.GetEncoded((Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate)chain[i], (Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate)chain[i + 1], null);// Propperties.OcspURL
                if (encoded != null) ocsp.Add(encoded);
            }

            PdfPKCS7 pdfPKCS7 = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, hashAlgorithm, true);
            pdfPKCS7.SetExternalDigest(Signature, null, "RSA");//ECDSA RSA 
            //byte[] sh = pdfPKCS7.GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, ocsp, null);
            //byte[] singedHash = GetSignedHash(Signature);
            var result = pdfPKCS7.GetEncodedPKCS7(hash, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, tsaClient, ocsp, null);
            //byte[] timestamp = tsaClient.GetTimeStampToken(Signature); // Get the timestamp from your TSA client
            //PdfDictionary sigDicCopy = new PdfDictionary();
            //ModifySigningDictionary(sigDicCopy);
            return result;
        }
}
```

Updated code, the class AudkenniSignature contacts a signature service that senda a message to the users phone or an app installed on the phoe in order for the user to sign the document, if i request an pkcs7 signature and retun it as is then it works but without a timestamp, this code trys to get the pkcs1 signature from the service and create a pkcs7 signature with an embedded timestamp.  the timestamp seems fine but in adobe reader the error is "the document has been alter or..."
thank you

Comment: What does your code sign? Your signature has authenticated attributes (you retrieve a copy of them in `sh`), so they should be signed. Apparently, though, you sign something else. Furthermore, it looks like you change a part of the signed document after finishing the signature container (you modify the signing dictionary). Thus, even if the signature in the signature container was correct, that document change thereafter would immediately invalidate the signature.

Comment: I am signing á pdf documents with itext 7. 
And If í request á pkcs7 signature and Just return it as is from the service then the signature is legal but lackin á timestamp, so í dont change the document.

Comment: By "What does your code sign?" I meant which bytes exactly. You call `Signature=class.Sign()` and it is completely unclear what that call does. In particular, though, it cannot sign the authenticated bytes you retrieve later.

Comment: this is the sign function in a class implementing IExternalSignatureContainer, the thrid party service can return a pkcs1 or a pkcs7, i am using pkcs1 so that i can add a timestamp to it.  when i request a pkcs7 signature and return it unchanged then the signature is legal in adobe reader.

Comment: *"this is the sign function in a class implementing IExternalSignatureContainer"* - that's the method you shared the code of in your question. But I asked about `Signature=class.Sign()` which is a different method, in particular not the method defined in `IExternalSignatureContainer`. And whichever bytes that method signs, they are the wrong bytes as the `byte[] sh` you retrieve later is to be signed.

Comment: I see, this is a class that send a phone no or idNumber to a service that then returns the signature and the certificate minus the private key, the code is supposed to be like this
 byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(data, DigestAlgorithms.GetMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm));
string authId = audkenniSign.InitSign(hashStr);
            audkenniSign.GetSignatureResult(authId);
I will update the code.

Comment: What do you use as `data` there? As mentioned twice before, it should be the `sh` you retrieve later.

Comment: as seen in the updated example, the data is the input stream into the sign function of IExternalSignatureContainer.  In order to get the sh parameter i will need the signature (pkcs1) before don't I.

Comment: As mentioned before, you sign the wrong hash. The `PdfPKCS7` class uses signed attributes (aka authenticated attributes), they are the data signed, not the plain stream you retrieve as input. *"In order to get the sh parameter i will need the signature (pkcs1) before don't I."* - Strictly speaking you only need the certificate before. I hope your signature API has a method for retrieving the X509 certificate of the signer before actually sending the hash to sign as that's what you need.

Comment: An alternative approach would be to request a pkcs7 signature and - before returning it - to request a time stamp for it and to add it to the signature container.

Comment: You say I need to get the sh and send that for signing, it would need to be digested, right? and assuming i can get the certs, they would not contain the private key, but i don't think i can get the certs before hand. 
If i get the PKCS7 signature, would i add the timestamp using the ModifySigningDictionary function Like: .Put(new PdfName("M"), timeStampToken);

Comment: *"You say I need to get the sh and send that for signing, it would need to be digested, right?"* - That depends on your signing service. Some signing services/devices do the hashing themselves, so you don't hash in your code. Some don't hash, so you do. Considering that in your running code with pkcs7 request your hashing is right, I assume you'll have to hash here, too. *"assuming i can get the certs, they would not contain the private key,"* - That's ok, you only need the public certificates early.

Comment: *"If i get the PKCS7 signature, would i add the timestamp using the ModifySigningDictionary function Like: .Put(new PdfName("M"), timeStampToken)"* - No. You would first take the pkcs7 signature container apart, identify the signature bytes, request a time stamp for them, add the retrieved time stamp as unsigned attribute to the SignerInfo substructure of the pkcs7, reassemble the pkcs7 now including the time stamp, and then return this changed pkcs7 object.

Comment: If you want to create PAdES baseline signatures, you could alternatively first sign the document with the plain pkcs7 from the signature server and then in another revision add a time stamp as document time stamp. These two ways are equivalent ways to constructs PAdES baseline T signatures. Except if the initial signature is a no-changes-allowed certification signature.

Comment: Using this:
'' 
PdfPKCS7 pdfPKCS7 = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, hashAlgorithm, false);
pdfPKCS7.SetExternalDigest(Signature, null, "RSA");//ECDSA RSA 
var result = pdfPKCS7.GetEncodedPKCS7(null, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, tsaClient, ocsp, null);//
return result;
''
Works even if the Signature is PKCS1, but if subFiler is ETSI_CAdES_DETACHED insted of Adbe_pkcs7_detached the the signature breaks.

Comment: And   using Adbe_pkcs7_detached,  https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/DSS/webapp-demo/validation show comment: AdES Validation Details:
The signed qualifying property: neither 'message-digest' nor 'SignedProperties' is present!
The signed attribute: 'signing-certificate' is absent!
Why is that?

Comment: That is because PAdES signing requires the presence of signed attributes while adbe_pkcs7_detached in its simplest firm does not.

Comment: Is there a way to fix that,  var result = pdfPKCS7.GetEncodedPKCS7(hash, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, tsaClient, ocsp, null); shows an error "document has been altered", and also if i add  byte[] sh = pdfPKCS7.GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, ocsp, null); and replace hash with sh, this is because the sh needs to be signed with the clinet cert, right? At this point I do have the Cert without the private key,

Comment: If you have the cert, you can then instantiate a `PdfPKCS7` with it and retrieve its authenticated attributes, the `sh` bytes. Then sign these bytes (you may have to hash first), call `SetExternalDigest` for this signature, and eventually call `GetEncodedPKCS7`.

Comment: the line var result = pdfPKCS7.GetEncodedPKCS7(hash, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, tsaClient, ocsp, null); add the signed hash, that is the content of the PKCS1 signature, is there not a way to retrieve the signed bytes from the PKCS1 signature?

Comment: You can retrieve the *hash* of the signed bytes from the pkcs1 signature but not the signed bytes themselves.

Comment: do you mean here i can retrieve the bytes from the PKCS1 that are signed and add it to line: pdfPKCS7.SetExternalDigest or pdfPKCS7.GetEncodedPKCS7 to get a legal PKCS7 Would that work and how do i get the bytes if it would work?
thank you